# UIView with a custom shaped frame containing content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I would like to take [image: this image] and place some `UIViews` inside the empty area.

How can I create a custom *container view* (the phone) with a "content" area that is equal to that empty space and is resizable?

I was using trial and error to get its *sub views* in there, but as soon as I resized the phone view, it all went out of whack.

Comment: I think you may want to read this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: I don't think that is a viable option. All of this is created in code

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question. Did you mean place `UIView`s inside that iPhone's `UIImage` or just `UIView`s on a blank `UIView`

Comment: I mean that the container view is the iphone , which has a content area for its subview which is inside the blank area

Comment: i misread the question sorry. but typically the view of the control can be used with addSubview and you just define the CGRect of the view.

Comment: When you resize your view you could check the value of self.bounds ( whatever view your in rectangle at the moment is this) then resize all subviews. if you had 8 views 2 wide 4 high, the width of each view could be self.bounds.size.width/2 and height self.bounds.size.height / 4.  Just update values of view.frame for each subview based  on current bounds when you triger a resize event. and don't forget to override (void) viewdidlayoutsubviews to handle an external resize like a flip. just check the bounds in this function and do work.

Comment: It's sufficient to update the value of each frame of every view on the screen to move them and resize them. Nothing else is needed.  You can look at your master views bounds and derive the math to make them all fit. If this is what you are looking for by a custom container view then let me know and i'd be happy to write up an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can take an ImageView and set the image above now have the set the frame of the view or views you want to add according to the frame u mentioned above

```
CGRect  viewRect = CGRectMake(10, 40, 320, 480);
UIView* myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewRect];
[imageview addSubview:myView];
```

If you want to add multiple view and want to slide the views you can take an Array of views and use page control.